# Перебор нескольких значений в массиве PHP. Как реализовать?

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь с массивами.

Есть функция ([плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mass-pagesposts-creator/)):

```
function mpc_ajax_action(){
    global $wpdb;
    $html = '';
    $prefix_word = sanitize_text_field($_POST['prefix_word']);
    $postfix_word = sanitize_text_field($_POST['postfix_word']);
    $pages_content = sanitize_text_field($_POST['pages_content']);
    $parent_page_id = $_POST['parent_page_id'];
    $template_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['template_name']);
    $type = sanitize_text_field($_POST['type']);
    $page_status = sanitize_text_field($_POST['page_status']);
    $authors = sanitize_text_field($_POST['authors']);
    $excerpt_content = sanitize_text_field($_POST['excerpt_content']);
    $comment_status = sanitize_text_field($_POST['comment_status']);
    $pages_list = sanitize_text_field($_POST['pages_list']);
    $page_list = explode(",", $pages_list);
    $html .= "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' >";
    $html .= "<thead><tr><th>Page/Post Id</th><th>Page/Post Name</th><th>Page/Post Status</th><th>URL</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    foreach ($page_list as $page_name) {
        $my_post = array(
            'post_title'     => $prefix_word.' '.$page_name.' '.$postfix_word,
            'post_type'      => $type,
            'post_content'   => $pages_content,
            'post_author'    => $authors,
            'post_parent'    => $parent_page_id,
            'post_status'    => $page_status,
            'post_excerpt'   => $excerpt_content,
            'comment_status' => $comment_status
        );
        $last_insert_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
    $url = get_permalink($last_insert_id);

        $html .= "<tr>";

        $html .= "<td> $last_insert_id</td> <td>".esc_html($page_name)." </td> <td class='status'> Ok </td><td> <a href='".esc_url($url)."' target='_blank'>".esc_url($url)."</a> </td>";   
        $html .= "</tr>";   
        add_post_meta( $last_insert_id , '_wp_page_template', $template_name);

    }
    $html .= "</tbody><table>";
    echo $html;
    wp_die(); 
}
```

Плагин позволяет генерировать страницы автоматически. Задаются значения полей, в частности название страницы ($pages_list) и контент страницы ($pages_content), но для каждого значения $pages_list присваивается одно и то же значение $pages_content, то есть для каждой страницы подставляется одинаковый контент.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы каждой странице подставлялся соответствующий ей в массиве данных контент.

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

а не как сейчас:

```
1 1
2 1
3 1
```

Данные представлены в формате

```
Название1, Название2
Контент1, Контент2
```

Comment: В чем проблема? Что пытались сделать?

Comment: У вас сейчас `$pages_content` объявлен ДО цикла и получен из массива `$_POST`. Конечно же, он будет одним и тем же, значение этой переменной вы никак не меняете в цикле, а по вашему вопросу неясно, как оно должно меняться хотя бы в теории.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо модифицировать цикл `foreach` таким образом, чтобы задействовать ключ массива `$page_name`. В этом случае, если ключи массивов `$page_name` и `$pages_content` совпадают, вы сможете воспользоваться ключом, чтобы сопоставить соответствующие элементы из двух массивов

```
$pages_content = sanitize_text_field($_POST['pages_content']);
$page_content = explode(",", $pages_content);
...
foreach ($page_list as $key => $page_name) {
        ...
        $my_post = array(
            ...
            'post_content'   => $page_content[$key],
            ...
        );
        ...
}
```

Обратите внимание, что и `$page_list` и `$page_content` должны быть массивами с одинаковым количеством элементов и с одинаковыми ключами.